What is the canonical divisor of a genus 2 curve?
Let $C$ be a genus 2 smooth curve and let $K_C$ be a canonical divisor. I know by Riemann Roch theorem that $deg(K_C)=2g-2=2$.

Can I specifically say what $K_C$ is linearly equivalent to? For example, is $K_C \cong 2p$ or $p+q$ for points distinct $p,q \in C$?


In general if you have any $deg =2$ divisor (need not be effective) can we say whether or not it is linearly equivalent to $K_C$?


If D is degree 2, then K_C - D is a point of the Jacobian of C, which is an abelian variety of dimension 2. So it’s far from clear whether D is linearly equivalent to K_C or not.

I am not sure if that is reason enough for a downvote. I apologise if you did not downvote.

Actually I did not downvote. Coincidentally enough, the downvoter did their action at the same time that I wrote my comment.

Thank you for your comment. I understand that for general D it's difficult to say anything. But what about for D=2p or p+q?

This is a bit tautologous but it may be worth mentioning to give a bit more geometric intuition: the linear system $K_C$ defines a morphism $C \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ of degree 2. A divisor in $|K_C|$ is the pullback of a point of $\mathbb P^1$ via this morphism.

@LazzaroCampeotti: Are there any methods or references to prove that $|K_C|$ is basepoint free?

@dhan: this is an exercise using Riemann--Roch. A reference is Hartshorne Chapter IV.

@LazzaroCampeotti: Thank you very much. I have found it.

One has $\dim|K_C| = 1$, so $K_C$ can be represented as $p + q$ in infinitely many ways (if the ground field is infinite), and even as $2p$ in six different ways (if the ground field is algebraically closed) --- the corresponding points $p$ are knows as Weierstass points.
If you have a divisor $D$ of degree 2 on a curve of genus 2, it is a canonical divisor if and only if $\dim|D| = 1$.
